# Multiple error: class, interface, or enum expected

Tags: java

```
public static boolean prime(int n){
    if(n<=1)
        return false;
    int z=2;
    if(n==2)
        return true;
    while(z<Math.sqrt(n)){
        if(z mod n==0)
            return false;
        z++;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Any clues what is wrong with my code?
I am receiving 7 errors of "class, interface, or enum" expecting...

Comment: About your algorithm, it would run faster if you'd start with z=3 and do z+=2 in your while loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"class, interface, or enum expected" error occurs mostly due to missing {} curly brackets. Check your program thoroughly.

If the above mentioned is all your code,then you should encapsulate it within a class.
Dont forget to write `main()` too.

There is no 'mod' keyword in java. Use '%' instead.

```
import java.util.*;

class Prime
{

public ...........main(.... args[])

{
//accept integer

if(prime(n))//calling prime()
..
}
```

and then your method..
Cheers!

Answer (score 4):

You cant execute stand alone code, everything must exist in a class, interface or enum.

This needs to live inside a class. This should be in a file called `MyClass.java`

E.g.

```
public class MyClass {

   public static boolean prime(int n){
       if(n<=1)
           return false;
       int z=2;
       if(n==2)
           return true;
       while(z<Math.sqrt(n)){
          if(z mod n==0)
              return false;
          z++;
       }
   return true;

   }  

}
```

It can then be called by running `MyClass.prime(7);`

As mentioned by others, mod is also an invalid keyword and should be replaced by the % operator

Comment: That is also wrong, but clearly not the error he is getting yet. Read the question title

Answer (score 2):

If this is all of your code, you will need to enclose it in a `class` as the error indicates :)

Secondly, there's no `mod` keyword in Java, replace with `%`. Putting the 2 together:

```
public class MyPrimeTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        boolean primeCheck = prime(43);
        ...
    }

    public static boolean prime(int n) {
        if (n <= 1) {
            return false;
        }
        int z = 2;
        if (n == 2) {
            return true;
        }
        while (z < Math.sqrt(n)) {
            if (z % n == 0) {
                return false;
            }
            z++;
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

- [Classes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classes.html)
- [Modulo operator](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/273783-the-use-of-the-modulo-operator/)